# Set top.location and open new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

i'm using the following code:

```
$('a[href*="somelinktext"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        top.location = "http://www.example.com";
    });
```

Is it possible to open a new window/tab with this link-click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.open` rather than `top.location`?

Comment: Yes, but note that in IE & Safari, the link would rather be opened in a new window. All other browsers will work as long as the tabs preference is set to create new tabs instead of windows.

Answer (score 3):

For opening a new tab/window (depending on the user's browser settings), simply add the `target` attribute. To change the location of the top-level frame of the current tab, you do need an onclick handler though.

```
$('a[href*="somelinktext"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank')
}).click(function(e) {
    top.location = 'http://www.example.com';
});
```

But if you **only** want to open a new tab, just stay with the `target` attr:

```
$('a[href*="somelinktext"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank')
});
```

You could also set it in the HTML code itself though:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">blah</a>
```

(it supports `_top` for the top level frame, too)

Comment: Huh.. I would have said `target="_blank"` as well, but I remembered that HTML5 specs said it was deprecated. Upon re-reading said spec, I found that it's no longer deprecated as "the target attribute for the a and area elements is no longer deprecated, as it is useful in Web applications". +1

Comment: I still wouldn't use it. It is **much** more user-friendly if they can decide - and nowadays most people (well, except some secretaries etc. :p) know how to use the middle mouse button anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use `window.open` function for that.

Thanks